# How to solve out *SPECIFIC* variables from a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to reduce  the size of a linear system by solving out some columns. For example:

$$
\mathbf{Ax = b} \\
\text{where } 
\mathbf{A=} \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1     \end{array} \right] \\
\text{and } \mathbf{b=} \left[ \begin{array}{c} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{array} \right]
$$

If I do it by hand, let's say I want to solve out $x_4$, by using the second row, I have :

$$
x_4 = b_2 - 5 x_3
$$

Now I can successfully reduce the size of my system as:
$$
\mathbf{A'x' = b'} \\
\text{where } 
\mathbf{A'=} \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -4  \end{array} \right] \\
\text{and } \mathbf{b'=} \left[ \begin{array}{c} b1 \\ b_3 - b2 \end{array} \right]
$$

Now what is the formal representation of this procedure? Is it possible to use a numerical solver to achieve this?

**clarification:**

I do not want to fully solve the system. The algorithms out there can do it for me. I want to pick a (defined by me) subset of the system variables and eliminate them. The question is, can I do it using the existing Gauss elimination algorithms?

Comment: I do not want to solve the system, it is underdetermined anyway. I just want to solve out specific columns.

Comment: Determining $n$ variables is equivalent to computing the first $n$ steps of [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). It does not reduce the dimensionality of your system though. There is no way to reduce dimensionality without losing information, i.e. without considering an _approximation_ of your initial matrix $A$.

Comment: I am sorry dimensionality was not the correct term. I meant size of my system .

Answer (score 1):

Each column corresponds to a variable.  If you reorder the columns so that the variables you want to eliminate correspond to the rightmost columns, then Gaussian elimination will solve for those column variables in terms of the later column variables (to the extent possible).

Comment: I don't think that you can extract $\mathbf{A'}$ from $\mathbf{A}$, with a simple reordering of $\mathbf{A}$ and an LU decomposition.